# List Items Background anchor link

Tags: html, css

I am working on this : [Menu List](http://jsfiddle.net/FN6f5/)

What I am trying to do is check with yourselves, If my approach is the right way. The site is running on Wordpress.

So ideally I'd like to get rid of the text "Our Services, About Us" etc.. But I'd also like the graphic to become a clickable anchor link.

Has anyone any ideas on the best way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give image inside `anchor`. Write like this:

```
.menu-header ul li a{
    display:block;
    padding: 70px 55px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

#access .menu-header ul li#menu-item-26 a{
    background: url(http://i41.tinypic.com/345h0cw.png) no-repeat;    
}

#access .menu-header ul li#menu-item-24 a{
    background: url(http://i43.tinypic.com/15cikhs.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#access .menu-header ul li#menu-item-23 a{
    background: url(http://i39.tinypic.com/dca82q.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/FN6f5/2/

Comment: Excellent. Few little things in your code that I hadnt thought about, particularly the IE7 stuff. Any idea on how I can get rid of the anchor text?

Comment: For get rid of the anchor text define this text-indent:-9999px;
 in your anchor css

Comment: Works a treat, Thanks @sandeep

Answer (score 0):

I would do this for removing the active link text. However i would suggest making each button image the same height so you can align them horizontally in a nice way. Widths can change but just adjust the css accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/FN6f5/3/