# Navigation menu with animation - Not the effect I need

Tags: jquery, css

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498303/list-items-background-anchor-link) the other day and got a great answer for it. Not thinking what I'd need next. My client has asked for the navigation items to animate on hover. So I started looking at [jQuery Spritely](http://spritely.net/). It seems to be exactly what I need, But with the setup of this menu now. I am not getting the right animation from it.

I have created this as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndHqx/) for you to look at. Basically I need the image to animate, But animate correctly. The spritely moves the background along, But as you can see from my jsFiddle its not doing it correctly.

Any help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new fiddle for simple explanation at http://jsfiddle.net/6ujRE/1/

Every frame of your image must be same size for nicer animation. I think your images not. Because of that the animation looks little bad.

1. First you should fix your image. (every frame must be equal)
2. Than implement my code to yours.

Comment: Thanks arunes. Every image is the same size.. Before converted to sprites they were : 140px x 170px

Comment: Its helped a litte thanks, Yeah. However adding that code to the other div's has caused an jQuery Error.